# GCC link a directory

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, linker

I want compile a .c script with the gcc-compiler.
But i need to link a file and a directory. I need to link the file `python3.lib` and the directory `D:\Python33\include`.
But the linker doesn't work, here my code:

```
gcc main.c -lpython3 -l D:\Python33\include
```

The Error:

```
main.c:1:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
#include <Python.h>
                ^
compilation terminated.
```

What is wrong? Thank you for help!

Comment: Why downrated??? 
This forum is so unfair, 1 downvote and i can't ask questions anymore!

Comment: "downrated" because you cannot possibly "link" a directory. And this is such elemenentary knowledge that the question therefore "fails to demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved." - In short: read the instructions :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing wrong parameters to gcc.

```
gcc main.c -L /path/to/lib/file/directory -lpython3 -I D:\Python33\include
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^            ^^^
```

Comment: I made it so: `gcc main.c -l python3.lib -I D:\Python33\include` but now there is the next error:        `  `d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot fin
d -lpython3.lib
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`
But the python3.lib it at the same directory like the main.c..what must i do?

Comment: Then use: `-L . -lpython3`. That is use `.` for the path.

Comment: For the path from what?

Comment: Ah, now: `gcc main.c -L D:\Python33\libs -lpython3 -I D:\Python33\include` .. but another Error:
`C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccN3E9Dl.o:main.c:(.text+0x26): undefined ref
erence to '_imp__PyRun_SimpleStringFlags'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`
Why is it so complicate?

Comment: Why downrated??? 
This forum is so unfair, 1 downvote and i can't ask questions anymore!